# Is the front address of std::vector move invariant?

Tags: c++, vector, stdmove

In the following snippet:

```
std::vector<double> a(100, 4.2);
auto* a_ptr = a.data();

auto b = std::move(a);
auto* b_ptr = b.data();

std::cout << ((b_ptr == a_ptr) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE") << '\n';
```

does the C++ standard guarantee that `b_ptr` is always equal to `a_ptr` after `std::move`? Running the code on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/) prints `TRUE`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) :

> After container move construction (overload (6)), references, pointers, and iterators (other than the end iterator) to other remain valid, but refer to elements that are now in *this. The current standard makes this guarantee via the blanket statement in §23.2.1[container.requirements.general]/12, and a more direct guarantee is under consideration via [LWG 2321](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-active.html#2321).

Pointers to elements are not invalidated, including pointers to the first element.

Comment: Hm, and is there no additional guarantee for end Iterators of a `std::vector`?

Comment: `cppreference` I think, not `cccpreference`. The latter should be for fans of the former USSR ;)